# Using FindFirstFile/FindNextFile to search for a file in EVERY directory.

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

So what I want to do is look for a program like "notepad", then it will start in C:\ drive to see if notepad is in there, if not load the top folder check in there, load those folders check, etc.

I just want the program to search every directory until it finally finds "notepad"

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\*", &file);
if (search_handle)
{
    do
    {
        std::wcout << file.cFileName << std::endl;
    } while (FindNextFile(search_handle, &file));
}
```

Comment: you probably want to use the [boost Filesystem Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: See [recursive file search](http://stackoverflow.com/q/978644/33499)